# Error in Django Rest Framwork. 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get the output from a Stored Procedure which I have written in MS SQL server into Rest API. I have succeeded in getting the Output. But I have failed in appending the output to rest api. Please help....

Here is my serializers.py code:

```
class Get_Count_Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ErRegisteredUsers
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Here is my views.py code:

```
from django.db import connection
from .serializers import *
from .models import *
from rest_framework import viewsets

class Get_Count_Viewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[ER_Get_Registration_Types_Count]')
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    #result = dict(results)
    queryset = results
    serializer_class = Get_Count_Serializer
```

This is my urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('Get_Count', views.Get_Count_Viewset, basename='Get_Count')
# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
```

This is the error I'm getting,

[image]

Comment: The output of stored procedure is in JSON format

Comment: Seeing that full traceback, preferably as string, would be useful here.

Comment: You're calling and executing the query inside the class definition - it executes once when file is loaded and that's it. You want it to execute on every request. More importantly that query returns a result row, not an instance of your model. Try a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries).